# Yarn: how to globally disable color output

Tags: yarnpkg

In the newer versions of the `yarn` package manager, almost all the commands have a `--no-color` option.

I'm running yarn under a continuous integration server (Jenkins) and the color escape chars pollute the output. I'd like to put something in the `.yarnrc` file to prevent the output of these escape chars. But I'd also to leave it on for when the developers run it on the terminal.

How to globally configure the --no-color option?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the environment variable `FORCE_COLOR` to `0` to disable any colored output (this option comes from [`chalk`](https://github.com/chalk/chalk#chalksupportscolor) which is used by `yarn` to output color).

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:10'
        }
    }

    environment {
        FORCE_COLOR = '0'
    }

    stages {
        stage('run yarn') {
            steps {
                sh 'yarn'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've set the variable and it still generates the color coding: `â”œâ”€â”¬ @angular/cli@1.7.4
â”‚ â”œâ”€â”¬ portfinder@1.0.13
â”‚ â”‚ â””â”€â”¬ debug@2.6.9 `

Comment: Looks like that's emoji output, not color. Try calling yarn with `yarn --emoji false`